# `OfficeClickToRun.exe` occasionally throws an error without Office being open

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, office365

I got an odd error today regarding the file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\ClickToRun.exe`: The device did not have the permissions to run (or something, I closed the prompt before getting a screenshot)

I was not using any Office product, nor had I since my last reboot. I searched for information regarding this file, and there is not enough information regarding the provenance of my specific file. I've checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and the Task Manager startup tab, but there's no indication I have any unknown system startups. I know the file is sometimes a legitimate file, but the fact that it threw an error when I was not interacting with Windows products worries me.

What are the chances that this file is actually malware?

Update:

[This MS Answers forum answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_win10/officeclicktorunexe-random-error/891339f8-0f54-4eca-ae2d-d1c1eff299b2) includes the exact error, which is "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." This seems to imply that the file doesn't exist, when I can clearly locate the file.

If another of this error pops up, I'll screenshot it.

Comment: In order to answer this question you must provide the exact error you received.

Comment: The OfficeClickToRun.exe file runs as service. It seems to manages resource coordination, background streaming, and system integration of Microsoft Office products and their related updates. If Office 365 is installed on your computer, this service may run background even you are not using Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any pending office updates (mentioned under the 'Product Information' section on the Office product's 'Account' screen) do you experience the same error when selecting the following 'Update Now' option?:

[image: Update Now Option]

If so, running a quick repair, via the change option under Programs and Features, may stop the error appearing and allow the pending update to be downloaded and applied.